# Wordpress: Creating a nonce for AJAX with multiple file references

Tags: ajax, wordpress, sql-injection

I'm a little confused on how to create a nonce for preventing SQL injection. Here are some samples from my code on how everything ties together.

```
function datafunction(stateId,jobId) 
        {   
            var strURL="<?php echo URL_CONSTANT ?>filename.php?state="+stateId+"&job="+jobId;
    // Irrelevant code          
                req.open("GET", strURL, true);
                req.send(null);
            }

        }
// *Separate file* Storing passed parameters into local variables
$state = $_REQUEST['state'];
$city = $_REQUEST['city'];
```

wp_create_nonce appears to have you do the creating in two separate places. Can anyone provide a little clarity on this? Thanks so much!

Comment: [Nonces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) are not used to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: See [WordPress Nonces](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).